# How do I find the exception type of an exception that gets thrown in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

I am using a library that doesn't seem to document the exceptions. This library is used to communicate with a product the company makes. I want to be able to differentiate between the exceptions that get thrown but I don't know the names of the exceptions (for example between a communication timeout or under-voltage condition).

All of their examples only use `catch(Exception ex)`. How can can I find what I need to use to catch the individual errors? When I do `ex.toString()` I get something like this:

```
System.Exception: Timeout
    at CMLCOMLib.EcatObj.Initialize()
    at copley_cmo_test.MainWindow.btnConnect_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
in c:\Users\adam.siembida\Desktop\copley_cmo_test\copley_cmo_test\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 41
```

Comment: You can use `ex.GetType()` to get the real type, but from the exception message it looks like they are throwing `Exception` directly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This:

```
System.Exception: Timeout
```

shows that they're just throwing a bare `System.Exception`, e.g.

```
if (weHaveNoApiDesignSkills)
{
    throw new Exception("Timeout");
}
```

It's possible that there are *some* exceptions which are better designed, but the one you've shown isn't promising :(

Unfortunately unless you start using the message in the exception to differentiate between them (which is almost *always* a bad idea) you're stuck. It may be worth asking the authors of the library to see if they can improve matters for a future release.

Comment: I would say it is always a bad idea to differentiate by message

Comment: It would be nice to also have a comment about how to identify the specific types of an exception if there are any better ones in there.

Comment: Why is it bad to differentiate by messages?

Comment: @w1res: It's very fragile - the developer can change the message between releases, e.g. to fix typos. Some developers may decide to internationalize their messages, too.

Answer (score 3):

Catch it with a catch-all construct such as `catch(Exception ex)`, then examine the `Type` returned by `ex.GetType()`. If it's equal to `typeof(Exception)`, it means that they aren't throwing anything more specific than `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, if you're stopped when the exception has been caught (ie, in a catch block), if you enter `$exception` in the watch window, you will see the entire exception.

Answer (score 0):

When the API in library which you are using is not documented properly , you should catch the base exception and log it not only by the message instead whole exception by converting the exception to string  . Eg.

```
   try
   {
       //api call which throws exception.
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       //log ex.ToString();       
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

use a decompiler for example:

http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

in .net there's no explicit exception declaration like in java so as i see it it's the only way.